# Positioning background:url with zindex

Tags: html, css, joomla

Here's one for you that has me stumped:

I'm using `background:url` to put a small image in the bottom right corner of my container within css which works nicely. However, when users are on the account creation page, the section that has the "create account" and "cancel" buttons is overlapping with my image, obscuring half of it. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I have looked into using z-index to fix this issue to no avail (since the image is a part of the container, if I decrease the z-index for the obscuring div, the whole section with the buttons is put behind the container which makes them impossible to see). I also don't want to go into each page individually and put the image into the html, especially since I'm using Joomla and the template html structure is pretty confusing for me. (Using Joomla 3.0.3 with the default Protostar template)

Am I missing something obvious? I feel like I am...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're funny :) Using a background image but wanting to put it in the foreground.

Just use an image tag and `position` it `absolute` in the bottom right of the container (don't forget to give the container `position: relative`)

Comment: Ok that is a fair point but in Joomla the html files are all over the place (some in httpdocs, some in the template folder etc) so using background image allowed me to do it just once and in the css file, which is easy to find...

*edit: can't think straight at the moment so I feel like my answers will keep getting dumber. I'll sleep on it, try your suggestion, and then probably come back and select it as the correct one :) but in the meantime if anyone has a specific walkthrough for this in Joomla I'd welcome it!

Comment: And yes your were right, naturally. I managed to find the right html doc and add in what you suggested. Thanks a heap for helping me with this (admittedly simple) problem :)